# Logic in SQL Select * Into From statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to write logic in a SQL `SELECT * INTO ... FROM ...` statement as stated below.

```
SELECT 
    ul.LocationCode
    ,ul.BusinessName LocationName
    ,ul.Email
    ,[First Name] ContactName
    ,[Last Name] ContactName2
    ,ul.Telephone Phone
    ,[Address 1] Address
    ,[Address 2] AddressLine2
    ,ul.City
    ,ul.[State]
    ,ul.Zip
    ,[Corp ID] CustomField5
    ,ul.Country
INTO
    #P10TempTable
FROM
    $(LinkedDatafeedDatabaseName).dbo.[fs_UserList] ul
LEFT JOIN 
    @DoNotDeleteLocations dnd ON dnd.locationcode = ul.locationcode
WHERE 
    id IS NULL
    AND ul.locationcode != ''
    AND ul.locationcode IS NOT NULL
```

When I am going to insert data into `#P10TempTable` with the help of these tables.

In this code I have required state code instead of state full name (for state column `ul.[State]` I am using `fs_UserList` table). `fs_UserList` table created based on user provided list.

Sometimes user provides the full name of state instead of state code. I am using `BusinessUnitReferenceValue` table for match state full name to state code.

When user provides the full name of the state, how can I determine the state code and use that in `#P10TempTable` state column?

Please help me write a logic to convert state name to state code in this SQL statement

Comment: Sounds like you need a look up table, where you have a list of the states abbreviates and full names in 2 columns (i.e. `'NY'` and `'New York'`). The  `JOIN` to that table and display `StateName` column from your lookup table.

Comment: I have find the data for state code with the help of below query. So now can you please tell me, How can i use this in select * into from condition in ul.state column name.(And BusinessUnitReferenceValue have two column State_FullName, State_Code and user_list table have  column state. I want a case when State_fullName = State then State_Code if State_code = State then state)
select rv.ReferenceResourceMessageKeyName,rv.ReferenceValue,ul.state from  BusinessUnitReferenceValue rv
Join User_List ul
on rv.ReferenceResourceMessageKeyName = ul.[State]
where rv.BusinessUnitID = 336

Comment: That SQL is just what you had in your question (it seems). Like I said, create a table, with all the states, and `JOIN` to it. Seems you already know how to perform a `JOIN`, so you should be able to implement this. if you don't understand how to `CREATE` and `INSERT` into a table, or perform a `JOIN` then you should be able about that. but then that means you don't udnerstand the SQL above, and if so you shouldn't be using it.